# Les $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma ^2)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal N(\nu,\theta^2)$. Show that $X,Y$ independent $\iff Cov(X,Y)=0$.

Tags: probability

Les $X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma ^2)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal N(\nu,\theta^2)$. Show that $X,Y$ independent $\iff Cov(X,Y)=0$.

The implication is obvious. But I have problem for the converse. Let $Cov(X,Y)=0$ i.e. $\mathbb E[XY]=\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y]$. How can I see that $\mathbb P\{X\in A,Y\in B\}=\mathbb P\{X\in A\}\mathbb P\{Y\in B\}$ ?

Comment: It's not true as stated.  You have to assume that $(X,Y)$ have a joint (bivariate) normal distribution.  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d/30205#30205

Comment: @NateEldredge: So $X,Y$ must have the same distribution ?

Comment: @user380364:  no - their marginal distributions can have different means and variances.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution